# Python package not installing on the first attempt but installing on the second attempt

Tags: python, setuptools, astropy

Okay. So I am working on a python 2.7 based package called [starkit](https://github.com/starkit/starkit). I am installing it using the following commands:

```sh
curl -O https://raw.githubusercontent.com/starkit/starkit/master/starkit_env27.yml
# create env
conda env create --file starkit_env27.yml -n starkit
# activate
source activate starkit

# get starkit
git clone https://github.com/starkit/starkit
cd starkit

# install
python setup.py install
```

When I run the python setup command I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 65, in <module>
    get_debug_option(PACKAGENAME))
  File "/Users/97amarnathk/Documents/starkit/astropy_helpers/astropy_helpers/setup_helpers.py", line 125, in get_debug_option
    if any(cmd in dist.commands for cmd in ['build', 'build_ext']):
  File "/Users/97amarnathk/Documents/starkit/astropy_helpers/astropy_helpers/setup_helpers.py", line 125, in <genexpr>
    if any(cmd in dist.commands for cmd in ['build', 'build_ext']):
AttributeError: Distribution instance has no attribute 'commands'
```

But when I again do `python setup.py install`, it works perfectly. I am not able to find **why the package is not installing on the first attempt but on the second attempt?**

This happens irrespective of the underlying computer. And when I clone this repository somewhere else, the same error occurs on the first try, but not on the second. Why?

Comment: The package probably has some `setup_requires` packages that are downloaded and cached the first time you run it, but some bug somewhere is preventing it from continuing after downloading the prerequisite. The second time you run it the prequisite is already cached so it doesn't go down the same code path. That's just my guess based on the behavior. You should report this to the package maintainer or to https://github.com/astropy/astropy-helpers

Comment: Also FWIW the preferred way to install Python packages from source these days is to run `pip install .` from the directory containing the setup.py file. It's better not to run the setup.py directly unless you're sure what you're doing. If some documentation somewhere says otherwise then it's outdated by several years on this point...

Comment: @Iguananaut Downgrading setuptools to 36.2.0 worked. I still am not able to explain why though.

Comment: I'm sure it's a bug. I'd suggest reporting it if you haven't already.